# What is the best way to determine if there is variable interactivity between independent parameters in a prediction model

Tags: predictive-modeling, linear-regression, logistic-regression, hyperparameter-tuning

OK, the best way to describe this is with an example. (admittedly simplified)

I want to predict the speed of drivers on a motorway and I have two input variables

1. the nationality of the driver
2. how heavy it is raining

Clearly, these 2 are independent of each other, so throwing this into a simple linear regression I get something like speed = intercept + X1[Nationality] + X2Rain_In_Inches + Error

So I may infer from this that British drivers go 7mph slower than Turkish drivers and speed decreases by 2mph for every inch of rain - so far so good

However, the effect of rain is applied across the whole population here, what I am trying o determine is how rain affects the speed of English drivers vs Turkish drivers. For example, I might expect that one is hardly affected and the other is affected a lot.

Is there a neat way to do this without individually building a model for each category? The above is simple but I want to do it with lots of categories and more parameters

I feel like I'm missing something but cant determine what

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an interaction term to the linear regression model. An interaction term models the effect that one feature has at different levels of another feature.

If nationality is one-hot encoded, you will have to add a separation interaction term for each level of nationality. For example:
$$  Speed = β_0 + β_1Rain + β_2British + β_3Turisk + β_4(Rain*British)+ β_5(Rain*Turisk)+Error $$

Most statistical software programs can automatically create the one-hot encoding and interaction terms.

Comment: thanks, it was the magic term "interactive" that was missing from my thinking. lots of resources on this. thanks again